# Flutter : Field 'initScreen' should be initialized because its type 'int' doesn't allow null. int initScreen;

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, init

Field 'initScreen' should be initialized because its type 'int' doesn't allow null. int initScreen

[image]

[image]

This code is for onboarding screen that visible only one time, how can  i solve this error?

Comment: Have you tried to add lateinit?

Comment: Just add `late` in front of `int initscreen;` Without `late`, you must initialize any variable you declared at the moment of declaration.

Comment: Error is solved using late keyword in front of it, thank you so much :-)

Comment: @MrGyovka `lateinit` is Kotlin. Dart uses `late`.

Comment: Please provide the actual code (not an image)! It's easier to copy & paste for testers out there!

Answer (score 0):

When you're declaring data types like `int initScreen` or `String name` and other data types, It means it has **an appropriate value**.

When the value of the data type will initialize later  with some operations and logic, you have to add `late` before of your data type like `late int number`.

When you're not sure the value of initializing is `null` or not, you can declare like this `int? number`, this mean it can have **appropriate value** or `null`.